# Creating 2d int table from text file. Output being (probably) blocks of memory

Tags: c++, c

I've been trying to create a 2d table from what I have put in text file. The text file itself is 20x20 and consists of only '0' and '1' without any whitespaces, only enter is used between the rows. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int z;
    int tabLab[20][20];


    //Drawing default map

    FILE * pLab;
    pLab = fopen ("labirynt.txt", "r");

        while((z = fgetc(pLab)) != EOF) {

            if(z == '0') {
                cout << (char)219 << (char)219;
            } else if (z == '1') {
                cout << "  " ;
            } else if (z=='\n') {
                cout << endl;
            }

    //Saving default map to 2d table

        }

            ifstream plLab;
                plLab.open("labirynt.txt");

                if(plLab.good()==true)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < 21; j++)
                    {   
                        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                        {   
                            plLab>>tabLab[j][i];
                        }
                    }
                }
    cout << endl;

    //Checking if table has been created correctly 

    for (int k = 0; k < 21; k++) {

        for(int l = 0; l < 21; l++) {

            cout << tabLab[k][l];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

I've been trying to fix the problem of the output, which comes out as big, random numbers, but so far I haven't managed to repair it.

Comment: Why are you iterating till `21` at several places, when you have 20x20 array? And why are you mixing C and C++ file libraries?

Comment: In what way is this C code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code, but most of all it lacks some error checking of input data and you are using wrong boundaries in the loops.
Look at this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define ROWS 20
#define COLS 20

int main() {
    int tabLab[ROWS][COLS];         // You are using int, but till now you have to store only 0 or 1...

// ---------- Read the input file, populating the 2d array --------------

    char inFileName[] = "labyrinth.txt";       
    char c;
    std::ifstream inFileLab;
    inFileLab.open(inFileName, std::ios_base::in);
    if ( !inFileLab.good() ) {
        std::cerr << "Error: I can't open the file " << inFileName << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < COLS; j++ ) {
            if ( !inFileLab.get(c) ) {
                std::cerr << "Error: I can't read element (" << i + 1 << ", " << j + 1 << ") in file " << inFileName << std::endl;
                exit(2);
            }
            if ( c == '0' ) 
                tabLab[i][j] = 0;
            else if ( c == '1' )
                tabLab[i][j] = 1;
            else {
                std::cerr << "Error: Wrong value read for element (" << i + 1 << ", " << j + 1 << ") in file " << inFileName << std::endl;
                exit(3);        // You can choose to set table[i][j] = 0 or 1 and continue;
            }
        }
        if ( i < ROWS - 1) {    // if the last row doesn't end with a newline it's not a big deal.
            if ( !inFileLab.get(c) ) {  
                    std::cerr << "Error: Abnormal line termination at row " << i + 1 << " in file " << inFileName << std::endl;
                    exit(4);                        
            }
            if ( c != '\n') {
                std::cerr << "Error: Line " << i + 1 << " is too long in file " << inFileName << std::endl;
                exit(5);                    
            }
        }
    }                           // The file can be bigger, I just ignore the extra data
    inFileLab.close();          //  and close the file (that could be tested too)

// --------------------- Show the 2d array -------------------------------

    const char block = 219;
    for ( int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < COLS; j++ ) {      // Like in your program, if t[i][j] == 1 you print space, blocks otherwise
            if ( tabLab[i][j] ) std::cout << "  ";  // Imho, the opposite would be better...
            else std::cout << block << block;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

// -------------------- Save the 2d array in another file -------------------

    char outFileName[] = "labyrinth_copy.txt";       
    std::ofstream outFileLab;
    outFileLab.open(outFileName, std::ios_base::out);
    if ( !outFileLab.good() ) {
        std::cerr << "Error: I can't open the output file " << outFileName << std::endl;
        exit(5);
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < ROWS ; i++) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < COLS; j++ ) {
            outFileLab << tabLab[i][j];
            if ( !outFileLab.good() ) {
                std::cerr << "Error: I can't save element (" << i + 1 << ", " << j + 1 << ") in file " << outFileName << std::endl;
                exit(6);
            }
        }       
        outFileLab << std::endl;
        if ( !outFileLab.good() ) {
            std::cerr << "Error: I could save only " << i << "rows out of " << ROWS << " in file " << outFileName << std::endl;
            exit(7);
        }
    }                           // The file is closed automatically when execution goes out of scope

// --------------------------------- Everything went fine ---------------------------
    return 0;
}
```

You can make even more improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a much simpler case. (You should always start with the simple and build up to the complex.)

labirynt.txt:

```
1011
```

In the code:

```
int n;
plLab.open("labirynt.txt");
plLab>>n;
cout << n << endl;
```

This produces:

```
1011
```

Clearly the code did not know that you intended to read only one character of the file. So when you tried to read the whole file this way, you read past the end and failed to set the values of most of the entries in the table, so they contained random junk.

There are several ways to solve this problem, and this is one of the simplest:

```
int n;
char c;
plLab.open("labirynt.txt");
plLab >> c;
n=0;
if(c=='1')
  n=1;
cout << n << endl;
```

From this you can build up to the table-filler.

Answer (score 0):

If you write numbers without spaces to text file like this:

```
fout<<1<<0<<1<<0
```

when you read it to int, you'll get the whole 1010 since string streams reads until the first white space and it will be the end of line.

You can solve it in many ways: for example, by read char after char:

```
//inside the read loop
char temp;
plLab>>temp;
tabLab[j][i]= (temp == '0') ? 0 : 1;
```